# Result of Ruby `String#split` method

Tags: ruby, string, split

I cannot explain the behavior of this code:

```
str="../tests/sls_79.sexp"
str.split(".") # => ["", "", "/tests/sls_79", "sexp"]
```

Where does the first element `", "` come from? Why such comma?

Comment: The first and second elements are both empty strings. The comma is the separator in the result array.

Comment: Maybe there might be some option like in .NET string split where you can discard empty strings...not a ruby guy so I won't know...

Comment: Actually, the first element is empty string "". The comma is used to separate the elements of the array.  The way that split works is by dividing your string into substrings based on your delimiter ( in your case is dot . ). The empty strings from your array comes from the fact that your string starts with two dots, which is your delimiter.

Comment: Oh !!! I see it now. Sorry guys !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you seek is all in [the `split` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-split):

> `split(pattern=$;, [limit]) → anArray`
>
> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings.
>
> [...]
>
> If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.
>
> When the input str is empty an empty Array is returned as the string is considered to have no fields to split.

Working from that information, `split` sees these as empty strings and returns empty arrays because there's nothing else to return:

```
'.'.split('.')  # => []
'..'.split('.') # => []
```

If there's something to return, `split` breaks the string into as many empty elements in the array necessary to reflect the delimiters found, then returns the sub-string:

```
'..foo'.split('.')    # => ["", "", "foo"]
'.foo.foo'.split('.') # => ["", "foo", "foo"]
```

At that point, the result you got should make sense:

```
str = '../tests/sls_79.sexp'
str.split('.') # => ["", "", "/tests/sls_79", "sexp"]
```

And, for thoroughness, as per the documentation, normally empty trailing elements are trimmed. `-1` tells `split` to retain trailing empty elements:

```
'.foo.'.split('.')     # => ["", "foo"]
'.foo.'.split('.', -1) # => ["", "foo", ""]
```

But wait! There's actually a better way to do what you're trying to do, use the methods designed to work with filenames!

We can `split` a file path into the directory and the filename.ext, or just extract the directory, just the basename of the file, or the extension of the file:

```
File.split(str)    # => ["../tests", "sls_79.sexp"]
File.dirname(str)  # => "../tests"
File.basename(str) # => "sls_79.sexp"
File.extname(str)  # => ".sexp"
```

Finally, here's how to get just the filename without the extension:

```
File.basename(str, File.extname(str)) # => "sls_79"
```

or you can use:

```
File.basename(str, '.*') # => "sls_79"
```

See the [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Because your string begins with two periods ("..")

```
 "../".split(".")
 => ["", "", "/"]
```

Try:

```
str="../tests/sls_79.sexp"
str.split(/\.+/) #=> ["", "", "/tests/sls_79", "sexp"]
 => ["", "/tests/sls_79", "sexp"]
```

Comment: why the comma in my result ?

Comment: because it's an Array not a string, what do you need to do?

Comment: I though the first element itself was a ",  "... Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method works. Taking your string:

```
str = "../tests/sls_79.sexp"
```

Splitting with a dot delimiter ".", will look in the string and find the delimiter. Since nothing was before it `split` will insert the first sub-string, which is an empty string.

```
split_result = [""]
```

Going forward, immediately another occurrence of a period, and again nothing was between this occurrence and the previous one, so `split` creates another empty sub-string for the array.

```
split_result = ["", ""]
```

The third occurrence happens after "9", resulting in a sub-string of "/tests/sls_79".

```
split_result = ["", "", "/tests/sls_79"]
```

Finally, the remaining sub-string will be added as a last element of the returned array.

```
split_result = ["", "", "/tests/sls_79", "sexp"]
```